# how to remove backslash from a string containing an array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this

```
a="[\"6000208900\",\"600020890225\",\"600900231930\"]"
#expected result [6000208900,600020890225,600900231930]
```

I am trying to remove the backslash from the string.

```
a.gsub!(/^\"|\"?$/, '')
```

Comment: Okay so how do i remove this double quote character?

Answer (score 6):

[Inside the double quoted string(`""`)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Double_quotes), another double quotes must be escaped by `\`. You can't remove it.

Use `puts`, you can see it is not there.

```
a = "[\"6000208902912790\"]"
puts a # => ["6000208902912790"]
```

Or use [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a = "[\"6000208902912790\"]"
=> "[\"6000208902912790\"]"
irb(main):003:0> b = JSON.parse a
=> ["6000208902912790"]
irb(main):004:0> b
=> ["6000208902912790"]
irb(main):005:0> b.to_s
=> "[\"6000208902912790\"]"
```

**update** (as per the last edit of OP)

```
irb(main):002:0> a = "[\"6000208900\",\"600020890225\",\"600900231930\"]"
=> "[\"6000208900\",\"600020890225\",\"600900231930\"]"
irb(main):006:0> a.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
=> [6000208900, 600020890225, 600900231930]
irb(main):007:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code `a.gsub!(/^\"|\"?$/, '')` can't remove the double quote characters because they are not at the beginning and the end of the string. To get what you want try this:

```
a.gsub(/((?<=^\[)")|("(?=\]$))/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=> a = "[\"6000208902912790\"]"
=> a.chars.select{ |x| x =~ %r|\d| }.join
=> "6000208902912790"
=> [a.chars.select { |x| x =~ %r|\d| }.join]
=> ["6000208902912790"] # <= array with string
=> [a.chars.select { |x| x =~ %r|\d| }.join].to_s
=> "[\"6000208902912790\"]" # <= come back :)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a="["6000208902912790"]" will return  `unexpected tINTEGER`error;
```

so `a="[\"6000208902912790\"]"`is used with `\` character for double quotes.

As a solution you should try to remove double quotes that will solve the problem.

Do this

```
a.gsub!(/"/, '')
```